# is there the equivalent of R's dput in Neo4j?

Tags: r, neo4j, cypher, r-neo4j

I would like to make a minimal viable example of a graph in Cypher. I'm searching for an equivalent of R's `dput` function to do so. I haven't been able to find anything. If anyone has a workaround or some wisdom to share it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As minimal examples for graphs did you see: http://neo4j.com/graphgists/

And for integration of R with Neo4j including graph examples: http://neo4j.com/developer/r